# How do I backup bad CD‐ROM?

Tags: linux, backup, drm, copy-protection, bypass

I have some CD‐ROMs with same origin which are difficult to copy.

When I insert them (one disc at once), I see one audio disc and one data disc in my file manager.

It is possible to access and copy data from each partition without issues, but when I use GNU tools on `/dev/sr0`, I see I/O errors. `dd conv=noerror` displays lot of I/O errors, but 0+0 (run for 400 seconds).

How do I backup them?

Comment: try `ddrescue` which will keep retrying error blocks, and skipping them if they are truly unreadable, instead of giving up.  For the audio portion try a program called Exact Audio Copy which does the same thing but for audio.

Comment: @LawrenceC, will it create single image including both data and audio? Also I don't think trusting software with no source code available is good idea. In addition, it cannot be verified because only insecure MD5 and SHA‐1 hashes are available.

Comment: These are very likely CD-ROMs with some sort of copy-protection mechanism (or hybrid audio CDs with extra stuff in a CDROM data session). Try using `cdparanoia` to convert the audio data to WAV files. You said you can copy the data, so I assume that part works fine. You can also use `cdrecord` etc. to see the table of contents (TOC) and session list.

Comment: @LawrenceC, "Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)" looks like to be very slow. Is it OK to wait two days?

Comment: @dirkt, audio data is already converted to files on CD‐ROM.

Comment: @LawrenceC, it finally finished. I'm unable to mount resulting iso and `file` says it is just "data". It is hybrid audio/software CD.